# I cannot sign out from Firebase in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a login interface in React using Firebase, but when I try to log out the user (using the logout button in the App component), I am redirected to the login page, and after a few seconds, I am redirected back to /app (where I shouldn't have access anymore), and it shows that I am still authenticated if I use FirebaseIsConnected() (from the attached code). Here's a brief summary of the attached code: AuthContext contains auth (which I use in Firebase), isConnected is a state that checks whether the user has access to the login and app pages or not. I most likely miss a promise, but I can't figure out why I can't log out. Thank you!

Furthermore, if there is a better method to protect the links, please let me know.

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useContext,
  useRef,
  createContext,
} from "react";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate, Navigate, Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function RouterManager() {
  let auth = FirebaseGetAuth();
  let [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(true);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, isConnected, setIsConnected }}>
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route path='/' element={<Home />} /> */}
        <Route
          path='/login'
          element={
            isConnected === null ? (
              <div>Loading</div>
            ) : !isConnected ? (
              <Login />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to='/app' replace />
            )
          }
        />
        <Route
          path='/app'
          element={
            isConnected === null ? (
              <div>Loading</div>
            ) : isConnected ? (
              <App />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to='/login' replace />
            )
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Login() {
  let { auth, isConnected, setIsConnected } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const emailRef = useRef("");
  const passwordRef = useRef("");

  const [displayStatus, setDisplayStatus] = useState(<></>);
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //get email and password from input fields
    const emailValue = emailRef.current.value;
    const passwordValue = passwordRef.current.value;

    //check if email is valid

    FirebaseIsConnected(auth, (response) => {
      if (response) {
        setIsConnected(true);
        navigate("/app");
      } else {
        FirebaseSignIn(auth, emailValue, passwordValue, (code, message) => {
          if (code === 200) {
            setIsConnected(true);
            navigate("/app");
          } else {
            setDisplayStatus(code, message);
            setDisableButton((prevValue) => !prevValue);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    //clean up
    return () => {
      setDisplayStatus(<></>);
      setDisableButton(false);
      emailRef.current = null;
      passwordRef.current = null;
    };
  }, []);

  //display error message
  function errorDisplay(errorMessage) {
    return <div className='error-message'>{errorMessage}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex-column-center-center wh-100 background-color'>
      <div className='login-container container'>
        {displayStatus}
        <form
          className='login-form'
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            handleSignIn(e);
          }}>
          <label>Adresa de email:</label>
          <input
            type='mail'
            name='email'
            placeholder='utilizator@example.com'
            ref={emailRef}
          />

          <label>Parola:</label>
          <input
            type='password'
            name='current-password'
            placeholder='parola'
            ref={passwordRef}
          />

          <div className='flex-column-center-center'>
            <button
              type='submit'
              disabled={disableButton}
              className='btn btn-primary btn-sm'
              style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
              Autentificare
            </button>
          </div>
          {disableButton ? (
            <Link className='login-link-center'>Nu am cont</Link>
          ) : (
            <Link className='login-link-center' to='/signUp'>
              Nu am cont
            </Link>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  let { auth, isConnected, setIsConnected } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const signOut = () => {
    FirebaseSignOut(auth, (code, message) => {
      navigate("/login");
      setIsConnected(false);
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{isConnected}</div>
      <button onClick={signOut}>logout</button>
    </>
  );
}
export function FirebaseGetAuth() {
  const firebaseConfig = {}
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  return auth;
}

export const FirebaseCreateUser = async (auth, email, password, callback) => {
  try {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        callback(200, "Accont created");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        callback(errorCode, errorMessage);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    callback(0, e);
  }
};

export const FirebaseSignIn = async (auth, email, password, callback) => {
  try {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        callback(200, "Signed in");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        callback(errorCode, errorMessage);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    callback(0, e);
  }
};

export const FirebaseSignOut = async (auth, callback) => {
  try {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        callback(200, "User sign out");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        callback(0, error);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    callback(0, e);
  }
};

export const FirebaseIsConnected = async (auth, callback) => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      callback(true);
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
};
```

The only solution I found, which worked because it provided an error and prevented the code from running further, was to replace FirebaseSignIn(auth, emailValue, passwordValue, (code, message) => {...}) with FirebaseSignIn(auth, emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value, (code, message) => {...}) in the handleSignIn function in the Login component. This way, the errors were generated: emailRef.current.value and passwordRef.current.value are null.

I tried not to use Context and instead pass everything through props, but I have the same result.
I tried to use console.log to see if everything is happening in order, and the only thing I observed is that when I call the logOut function, I am redirected to the logIn page where FirebaseSignIn is automatically called, even though the HandleSignIn function is not called (I placed a console.log there, and it wasn't displayed). I searched through the documentation and other open topics, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `signOut()` function synchronously. It returns a `promise`, and need to wait for the promise to resolve.
try below,

```
  const signOut = async () => {
    try {
      await FirebaseSignOut(auth);
      navigate("/login");
      setIsConnected(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

and also try with this,

```
 const signOut = async () => {
    await Firebase.auth().signOut();
    navigate("/login");
    setIsConnected(false);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the code modifications as you suggested, and now, after clicking the button, I am redirected to the login page. However, if I refresh the login page, I am redirected back to the /app page. It's an improvement, but I'm still not logged out. """const navigate = useNavigate();
  const signOut = async () => {
    await FirebaseSignOut(auth, (code, message) => {
      navigate("/login");
      setIsConnected(false);
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{isConnected}</div>
      <button onClick={signOut}>logout</button>
    </>
  ); """

Comment: @JohnSm try with my updated code

Comment: It worked! It didn't work initially because I was initializing isConnected with true. I made a modification to let [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(null);. Thank you.